# Why does getCheckedItemPositions() return the inverse truth values

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` in multiple selection mode. Whenever I click an item, I want to handle that event. For this, I use the following logic.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    OverlayTypes selected = (OverlayTypes) getListAdapter().getItem(
            position);
    boolean isChecked = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions().valueAt(
            position);
    Log.i(TAG, position+" is "+isChecked);
}
```

But whenever an item gets checked, `getChecked` is 'false' and 'true' vice versa. Why?

Comment: What you want exactly , do you need the checked state or the positions which are checked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was overly ambitious in get the `getView()` method of my custom adapter. In `getView()`, I tried to set the `Checkable` view to the value that it has in my settings, not realizing that checked state is handled within the adapter.

If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It might be an issue with timing, the value of the checked box may not be updating until after you have printed out to the LogCat.

Try changing your line

```
boolean isChecked = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions().valueAt(position);
```

to

```
boolean isChecked = l.getCheckedItemPositions().valueAt(position);
```

to see if reading the local copy instead of your global copy helps.